# Geodesics on algebraic manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, real-algebraic-geometry

A nonsingular algebraic manifold is an **immersed manifold** (*slightly different from the usual embedded algebraic manifold*) $M \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ that is also a nonsingular algebraic set (which means $M$ is a closed set and without boundary). $M$ admits a natural Riemann structure derived from the usual inner product of $\Bbb{R}^n$. By Hopf–Rinow theorem $M$ is geodesically complete, so we may assume all geodesics mentioned below complete.

We call a geodesic **proper** if it can be realized by a **proper immersion** (*again not required to be an embedding*) of $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{S}^1$ into the manifold. For example, the geodesics of flat $\Bbb{T}^2$ with irrational winding are not proper.

My problem is: **What kinds of nonsingular algebraic manifolds have their every proper geodesic also algebraic?** (*We may call these manifolds g-algebraic and the remains g-transcendental.*) This question arose when I was visualizing the matrix-exponential 'geodesics' of Heisenberg group, where $\begin{pmatrix}1&a&c\\0&1&b\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ is embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$ as $(a,b,c)$.  <s>These geodesics seem to be quadric curves</s>  **As Robert Bryant commented (see below)**, there is no bi-invariant Riemann structures on the Heisenberg group, thus the integral curves of a left invariant vector field are never geodesics, causing uncertainty if the isometric immersion of such Heisenberg group into some $\Bbb{R}^n$ is g-algebraic.

**Partial Results**: It is clear that linear manifolds and spheres in any $\Bbb{R}^n$ and flat $\Bbb{T}^m$ in $\Bbb{R}^{2m}$ denoted by $x_{2i-1}^2+x_{2i}^2=1,1 \le i \le m$ are g-algebraic. Counterexamples are cylinders and hyperboloids of 1-sheet in $\Bbb{R}^3$, who have proper helicoid geodesics and thus are g-transcendental. Note that apart from linear cases, noncompact algebraic manifolds have a higher probability of admitting proper transcendental geodesics , which tend not to be closed and become improper on compact ones.

**About Lie group**: Contrary to my former thoughts, although Lie groups have geodesics in matrix-exponential form, many of them seem to be pure exponential or trigonometric and so can be realized as algebraic sets with respect to the canonical (but not isometric with respect to the bi-invariant metric) embeddings into $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$. Transcdental cases only happen when the group is not compact and there exists a matrix-exponential containing a mixture of functions of at least 2 of the following types: exponential, trigonometric and polynomial (*e.g. the exponential of a Jordan block of rank greater than 1*). I only found this happening in $GL(n,\Bbb{R})$ and $SL(n,\Bbb{R})$. An additional discovery is that the latter case only occurs for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: The compact rank one symmetric spaces isometrically embed in their Cartan embeddings in Euclidean space with all geodesics periodic, so they give you a few more examples.

Comment: @BenMcKay Is 'periodic' here equivalent to 'closed'? Why are periodic geodesics on algebraic manifolds also algebraic?

Comment: The geodesics of compact rank one symmetric spaces are periodic, and therefore closed as subsets. They are also embedded circles. They are algebraic in that particular embedding, since they embed as circles.

Comment: Periodic geodesics on algebraic manifolds are probably not algebraic, although I don't see an obvious example.

Comment: Tannery's pear is a singular algebraic surface in 3-dimensional Euclidean space whose geodesics are embedded circles, but not smoothly embedded.

Comment: I think that every smooth quadric hypersurface in Euclidean space has every geodesic either improper or a plane quadric curve. This should be easy to look up.

Comment: @BenMcKay Could you clarify your last comment - some ellipsoids are known to have non-planar closed geodesics, no?

Comment: @LeoMoos: I thought that the proper geodesics on the ellipsoid are only the three perpendicular planar ones along the major, semiminor and major axis. So maybe I have that wrong. I remember that the generic geodesic on the ellipsoid is not proper. Maybe the generic ellipsoid will be ok?

Comment: @BenMcKay: On the hyperboloid of 1-sheet $x^2+y^2 - z^2 = 1$, the unit speed geodesics that pass through the 'throat' $z=0$ with a positive vertical velocity that is less than $1/\sqrt2$ are properly embedded, but are not planar.

Comment: @RobertBryant Someone misled me by saying that a left translation of the expotential map at the unit is not always geodesic under the left invariant Riemann tensor. So I change 'left-' into 'bi-' without thinking twice.

Comment: @RobertBryant So there is even no left-only invariant Riemann structure on Heisenberg group? I am considering to replace the existence of Riemann structure with the existence of an affine torsion-free connection.

Comment: @BenMcKay Just for reference, this fact about ellipsoids is stated as Theorem 3.5.19 in Klingenberg's *Riemannian Geometry*. He defines some integral quantity $\omega = \omega(a,b,c)$ and claims that when $\omega > 2$ then there exist additional, non-standard simple closed geodesics. Klingenberg cites the following paper for this: Viesel. Uber einfache Geodatische auf dem Ellipsoid. *Arch. Math.* 22, 106-112 (1971).

Comment: @LeoMoos: thanks.

Comment: @Zerox:  You misread what I wrote.  I said that there is no biïinvariant Riemannian metric on the Heisenberg group, which is the case.  Of course, there *are* left-invariant Riemannian metrics, but none of those can have the the 1-parameter subgroups of the Heisenberg group as geodesics.

Comment: @Zerox: I deleted my earlier comments about the Heisenberg group $H$ because they contained errors. These are the correct statements: 1) There are no biiinvariant Riemannian metrics on $H$. 2) The torsion-free affine connection on $H$ whose geodesics are the left (and/or right) translates of the $1$-parameter subgroups of $H$ is flat (and complete, of course), so it is the Levi-Civita connection of a $6$-parameter family of (flat) Riemannian metrics. However, no one of these metrics is left or right invariant. 3) Most of the geodesics of a left invariant metric on $H$ are not algebraic curves.

Comment: @BenMcKay:  Your comment about Tannery's pear made me curious about how Tannery found his example, so I looked it up.  Your comment wasn't quite right.  In fact, the geodesics on Tannery's pear are *not* embedded circles, except for the meridians (i.e., profile curves) and the 'equator' (i.e., the parallel of largest radius), they wind twice around the 'poles' and self-intersect once by the time they close.  More amazingly, they are all *algebraic* curves, either hyperelliptic or rational.  Each such geodesic is the intersection of a surface of degree 4 and a surface of degree at most 10.

Comment: @RobertBryant: wow! I tried to get a PhD student to work on Tannery's pear, but he decided to do something else.

Comment: @BenMcKay:  Yes, it is amazing.  It makes me wonder whether there might be a nonsingular Zoll $2$-sphere of positive curvature (maybe even one with rotational symmetry) whose geodesics are all algebraic curves in its isometric embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Of course, regarded as an orbifold, Tannery's pear is *already* nonsingular.  It just has an orbifold point of type $1/3$ at the 'stem'.  If one were to take a nontrivial triple cover of a punctured neighborhood of the 'stem', the Riemannian metric on the triple cover would fill in smoothly (and nondegenerately) across the puncture.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I asked my PhD student what the Lebrun-Mason picture of the Tannery pear is like, from their paper on Zoll surfaces, but we never looked into it.